# Is there any observer like 'cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after' in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, event-observer, cataloginventory

I need to trigger the inventory changes in Magento 2.0
I have an observer `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after` in Magento 1.9 and its working fine.

But I can't find the same observer in Magento 2 (or) is there any other method for triggering inventory changes in Magento-2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento 2 basically it happens Dynamically  with `afterSave()` method

```
public function afterSave()
{
    $this->cleanModelCache();
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('model_save_after', ['object' => $this]);
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('clean_cache_by_tags', ['object' => $this]);
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch($this->_eventPrefix . '_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
    $this->updateStoredData();
    return $this;
}
```

The problem is in magento in core file `vendor\magento\module-catalog-inventory\Model\Stock\Item.php` as we know we generate name of event using this  `$this->_eventPrefix` this variable is not properly declared in item.php file

So change the line in `vendor\magento\module-catalog-inventory\Model\Stock\Item.php` around line number 35 from

```
protected $eventPrefix = 'cataloginventory_stock_item';
```

### **To**

```
protected $_eventPrefix = 'cataloginventory_stock_item
```