# Magento 2 : Stock Inventory Save After Observer - Issue

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3.2

This observer triggered only when Quantity is out of stock or when we save the Quantity. Is there any other Observer event in Magento when the Quantity get Change while creating an order from the backend that observer will trigger?

Comment: Is this observer is called when the admin form is submitted?

Comment: cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after

Comment: Your info is limited Please describe in brief so that someone help you.

Comment: I want when Quantity subtract from Catalog this observer need to triggered but this observer is triggered when Quantity is out of stock or When you save the Quantity from Catalog product

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183770/is-there-any-observer-like-cataloginventory-stock-item-save-commit-after-in-ma

Comment: I got the solution "sales_model_service_quote_submit_success"
This observer will trigger.